# Color Filter Technique OpenCV

Tags: javascript, opencv, camera, jpeg

I am reading a picture and filtering out the colors and this is the result I get in the following images. The code is from the example folder in the `opencv` module.

[image: Prior Color Filter] [image: Post Color Filter]

I am trying to feed the picture back to an `A.R Drone 2.0` and  have the drone follow the color white. How would I do the second part?

```
var cv = require('C:/users/danny/codes/node_modules/opencv/lib/opencv');

// (B)lue, (G)reen, (R)ed
var lower_threshold = [220, 220, 220];
var upper_threshold = [255, 255, 255];

//var lower_threshold = [46, 57, 83];
//var upper_threshold = [80, 96, 115];

cv.readImage('C:/users/danny/codes/node_modules/opencv/examples/files/gutter.jpg',
  function(err, im) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

    im.inRange(lower_threshold, upper_threshold);
    im.save('C://users/danny/codes/coin_detected.jpg');
    console.log('Image saved to C://users/danny/codes/coin_detected.jpg');
  });
```

Comment: By second part, do you mean calculating the trajectory to move the drone?  Or interfacing with the Parrot SDK (http://developer.parrot.com/)?

Comment: Moving the drone's trajectory to follow the white line. I have been using `node.js`. Don't know what SDK is.

Comment: This SDK is a software development kit for controlling drones.  Here's the link to the SDK documentation (http://developer.parrot.com/docs/SDK3/) for some of the Parrot drones.  I think your A.R. Drone 2.0 would correspond to the SDK2, which can also be found on the website.

Comment: The code I have is in javascript though. I don't think it is compatible

Comment: You can use javascript and the C API for the SDK: https://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone

Answer (score 3):

Since your drone can move in 3D-space, I will suggest some pseudo-code steps in the 2D realm to get you started with a simple line follower.  Then you can extrapolate to 3D and add more degrees of freedom to meet your needs.

1. Perform [Erosion/Dilation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) Operations on your image to get rid of extra space, if necessary.
2. Call [cv::findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) to get a trace around the edges of the white regions in your image.
3. Sort your found contours by pixel area to find the contour you want to follow.  I'd guess that you'd most often want to follow the largest pixel area.  Try using the [contour moments](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments).
4. Fit a line to the contour using [cv::fitline()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline) or your own approach.
5. Take the angle of the line and map it to your drone controller to adjust the yaw.

From here, you can do several other basic things to control the motion of your drone:

- Set a contour pixel mass threshold. If the contour area > threshold, move up.
- Look at the shape of the threshold area.  If it is more like a trapezoid than a rectangle, you can adjust your roll/pitch.

Comment: I look at those commands. Thank you for that. Can I write that in javascript. Or should I somehow call the `opencv` function to my node.js. Is that the right thinking? Can you give me a better idea of how to link the two languages together or am I thinking incorrectly.

Comment: is there a way to move the drone just using `opencv`. or do I need `node.js`

Comment: I am using this library:https://github.com/puku0x/cvdrone. How would I do what you mentioned with mapping to the drone controller. contour area > threshold