# OpenCV Object Detection/ Color Filtering

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading a picture and filtering out the colors and this is the result I get in the following images. The code is from the example folder in the `opencv` module. How can I do this continually with an A.R drone 2.0. So when the gutter is in the air, it detects the gutter from anywhere. So instead of having one picture saved, the drone finds the gutter, it filters out the gutter with color and it can follow that color in a straight line.

[image: Prior Color Filter] [image: Post Color Filter]

```
var cv = require('C:/users/danny/codes/node_modules/opencv/lib/opencv');

// (B)lue, (G)reen, (R)ed
var lower_threshold = [220, 220, 220];
var upper_threshold = [255, 255, 255];

//var lower_threshold = [46, 57, 83];
//var upper_threshold = [80, 96, 115];

cv.readImage('C:/users/danny/codes/node_modules/opencv/examples/files/gutter.jpg',
  function(err, im) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

    im.inRange(lower_threshold, upper_threshold);
    im.save('C://users/danny/codes/coin_detected.jpg');
    console.log('Image saved to C://users/danny/codes/coin_detected.jpg');
  });
```

Comment: Duplicate of your own two previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200804/color-filter-technique-opencv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184461/interfacing-open-cv-and-node-js  The community here is happy to help, but please show the progress you have made working on your code to get more informative answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is "Visual Odometry" which is the basis of many Augmented Reality systems.

What you need to do is:

1. Detect the gutter
2. Find gutter's position
3. Move drone along the position
4. Rinse and repeat as fast as you can

I found this blog that does something similar to what you want to do:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Comment: how do I move the drone?